# Google workbox offline analytics not working as expected

Tags: google-analytics, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am trying to follow the example in:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-google-analytics

I set up a Google analytics account, and then created a PWA using https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/workbox-lab/#0.
The PWA from the lab works as expected.

Then I created a custom dimension (dimension1) and a custom metric (metric1) in google analytics. When I send the dimension and metric in code on page load it shows up in the Google analytics reports.

```
ga('create', 'UA-125355230-1', 'auto');
//ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', { 'metric1': 100 });
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'online');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Then in the sw.js (the service worker js), I added the following code, as it says in the tutorial:

```
workbox.googleAnalytics.initialize({
    parameterOverrides: {
    dimension1: 'offline',
},
hitFilter: (params) => {
    const queueTimeInSeconds = Math.round(params.get('qt') / 1000);
    params.set('metric1', queueTimeInSeconds);
},
});
```

I stopped the app, and refreshed the index.html a few times. I brought the app back online and tried to sync the service worker by using the queue name workbox-background-sync:workbox-google-analytics.

This triggers the background plugin code, but it does not find anything to send.

Same results when I tried to make the network offline in devtools.

In debugger the createRequestWillReplayCallback of workbox-google-analytics.dev.js is called initially, but the replayRequests of workbox-background-sync.dev.js which is called when I try syncing seems to not find anything to replay.

During sync the

> workbox-background-sync - http://localhost:8081

is created in indexedDB, but the queueName under requests seem to be empty:

[image]

What am I missing? Any pointers or help to get the offline analytics working with Workbox and test PWA is appreciated.